# HTML form will connect with a database to store data

Tags: html, mysql

I have an existing HTML form, which is user submission form not a user registration form , now I want to keep all users submitted data to a database. can you please help ?

Comment: It is almost impossible for us to give you any significant help with the information that you have given here. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of the code in question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. What have you already tried?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is very very broad. Study about [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**MySqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
i just give you hint ok because it is very easy search and read ok
THIS IS HTMl CODING
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="submit" name="button">
THIS IS PHP
   if(isset($_POST['button']))
   {
    $text=$_POST['name']
   }

  $query="INSERT INTO table('column') VALUES('$text')";
```